# Is jQuery's "each()" method a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried adding a serialized class to each of a set of objects like this:

> ```
> jQuery('#preload img').each(function(){
>     jQuery('#thumbs').append('<img class="index' + index + '" src="' + source + '" />');
>     index = ++index;
>     });
> ```

And it worked. What resulted was a set of images, each with a class `image1`, `image2`, and so on. It's exactly what I wanted. But is this actually a reliable method of looping through a set of objects? Or is it possible that, if this anonymous function took longer to execute, the function might start on the next object before `index` is incremented?

Anybody know what's actually happening?

Comment: FWIW a more performant approach would be to initialize a blank string before that loop, concatenate to it each time through the loop, then `$(...).append` the string a single time after the loop finishes.  DOM is notoriously slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the inner workings of the `each` function (1.4.4):

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
    var name, i = 0,
        length = object.length,
        isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction(object);

    if ( args ) {
        if ( isObj ) {
            for ( name in object ) {
                if ( callback.apply( object[ name ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( ; i < length; ) {
                if ( callback.apply( object[ i++ ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
    } else {
        if ( isObj ) {
            for ( name in object ) {
                if ( callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( var value = object[0];
                i < length && callback.call( value, i, value ) !== false; value = object[++i] ) {}
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```

You can see here that it has a few different cases but all of them use `for` loops and call the callback function. So your code should be fine.

You can look it up in the development version of jQuery (change the radio button on the main jQuery site, or click [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js)).

Answer (score 5):

`.each()` is indeed essentially a for loop and it also has a built in index you can use if you pass in an argument like so:

```
jQuery('#preload img').each(function(i){
    jQuery('#thumbs').append('<img class="index' + i + '" src="' + source + '" />');
});
```

---

EDIT: Bonus implementation with Ken Franqueiro's string concatenation suggestion:

```
var thumbsAppend = "";
jQuery('#preload img').each(function(i){
    thumbsAppend += '<img class="index' + i + '" src="' + source + '" />';
});
jQuery('#thumbs').append(thumbsAppend);
```

---

EDIT #2: And rahul's array push suggestion:

```
var thumbsAppend = [];
jQuery('#preload img').each(function(i){
    thumbsAppend.push('<img class="index' + i + '" src="' + source + '" />');
});
thumbsAppend = thumbsAppend.join('');
jQuery('#thumbs').append(thumbsAppend);
```

Comment: Better to use an array push rather than string concatenation.

Comment: @rahul, only for IE7 and lower though, in other browsers both methods are about the same, except for safari where concats are faster.

Comment: ah the wonderful world of benchmarking. Truth be told, the difference between `strcat` and `arr.push` is insignificant compared to the diff between either and DOM adjustment. If it works on a reasonably slow computer (netbook?), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

http://api.jquery.com/each/

> are iterated by numeric index, from 0
>   to length-1